# How to use UIActivityIndicatorView with XML loading?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview, tbxml

I have a view where I get some content from a XML file with TBXML parser when I click a button. It looks like this in the clicked button method :

```
// Should be [activityIndicator startAnimating];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"adress.xml"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:data error:nil];
listArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
[self getData:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
// Should be [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

But the activityIndicator doesn't display... It's not a problem of its implementation because I see it if I add it at the beginning of the view... so I'm stuck. Any advice ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : here is the code :

My function, called when I click the button :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"adress.xml"];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                 DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:data error:nil];
        listArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
        [self getData:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

My getData function :

```
- (void) getData : (TBXMLElement *) element
{
    Offre *offre = [[Offre alloc] init];
    do {
        if(!go) if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"item"]) go = YES;
        if(go)
        {
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"title"]) [offre set_title:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"description"]) [offre set_description:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) [offre set_pubDate:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"link"]) [offre set_link:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"contract-type"]) [offre set_contractType:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"salary"]) [offre set_salary:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"fn-org"]) [offre set_fnOrg:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"locality"]) [offre set_locality:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"state"]) [offre set_state:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"filiere"]) [offre set_filiere:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"categorie"]) [offre set_categorie:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"statut"]) [offre set_statut:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"country-name"]) [offre set_countryName:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"tag"]) [offre set_tag:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
            if([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"familleMetiers"]) 
            {
                [offre set_familleMetier:[TBXML textForElement:element]];
                [listArray addObject:offre];
                offre = nil;
            }
        }
        if (element->firstChild) [self getData:element->firstChild];
    } while ((element = element->nextSibling));
}
```

I wonder if this isn't because of the recursivity of the function.

Comment: Have you tried to put a `NSLog` there? The async call looks fine to me. Are you using iOS 5? If yes, you could take advantage of `NSURLConnection` new API.

Comment: How long do you have to wait for the completion of this computation? Did you execute the startAnimating before starting the async computation?

Comment: Yes I did. And I have to wait 1-2 seconds with wi-fi connection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `dataWithContentOfURL` is taking long time. So it's better to do that in background. You can do like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"adress.xml"];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                 DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:data error:nil];
        listArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
        [self getData:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Flex_Addicted's post, it seems that my app doesn't go through dispatch_async function.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    activityview = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityview setFrame:CGRectMake(295/2, 375/2, 25, 25)];
    [self.tableView addSubview:activityview];
    [activityview startAnimating];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    /* Create our NSInvocationOperation to call loadDataWithOperation, passing in nil */
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                            selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation) object:nil];

    /* Add the operation to the queue */
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}

-(void)loadDataWithOperation {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"adress.xml"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:data error:nil];
    listArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    [self getData:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
    [activityview stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Yeah,just in case,if data takes time to load,this method will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you executing the downloading and parsing of the xml data. If you do it in the same thread, the main one, you won't see the indicator.

To avoid this, you could simply start the indicator, put the parsing in background and when finished, grab stop the indicator. For example using GCD, you could do:

```
// start the indicator

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(“com.app.yourtask”,NULL);

dispatch_async(queue,^{
 // your downloading and parsing here

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

   // stop the indicator
 });
});

// release the queue you create...
```

The other way is to delay the operation in the run loop.

```
- (void)setUpDataParsing {

  // start the indicator
  [self performSelector:@selector(parseData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)parseData {
  // your downloading and parsing here
  // stop the indicator
}
```

For further info take a look at [NSRunLoop Pogo Stick](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=15).

P.S. Rembember to add the indicator to a superview.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know why, but it looks like my app doesn't go through dispatch_async function... I tried a NSLog there and nothing is printed in the log...

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? Does your async call is called? Thanks.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. If I use the first method async isn't called and with the second one the parseData method isn't called.

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question and put the code there? Thanks.